# Script not populating MySQL database - do I have syntax errors?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am trying to populate a MySQL database by uploading contents of a SQLite database from my Android application. However when I do so the MYSQL database doesn't get populated.

The PHP script that I am trying to use to populate is as follows (note username, password etc are left out purposely, but are definitely correct). Are there any syntax errors or what could the issues be?

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['sessionId']) && isset($_GET['game']) && isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['avgMed']) && isset($_GET['maxMed']) && isset($_GET['avgAttn']) && isset($_GET['maxAttn']) && isset($_GET['score']) && isset($_GET['date'])
 && isset($_GET['rawFile']) && isset($_GET['EEGFile']) && isset($_GET['medFile']) && isset($_GET['attFile']))
{

$mysql_host = "";
$mysql_database = "";
$mysql_user = "";
$mysql_password = "";


    // Provide host ip, mysql user name, password
    $con = mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password);

    // Provide database name.
    mysql_select_db($mysql_database);

    $sessionId=$_GET['sessionId'];

    $game=$_GET['game'];

    $name=$_GET['name'];

    $avgMed=$_GET['avgMed'];

    $maxMed=$_GET['maxMed'];

    $avgAttn=$_GET['avgAttn'];

    $maxAttn=$_GET['maxAttn'];

    $score=$_GET['score'];

    $date=$_GET['date'];

    $rawFile=$_GET['rawFile'];

    $EEGFile=$_GET['EEGFile'];

    $medFile=$_GET['medFile'];

    $attFile=$_GET['attFile'];

    $flag="false";


    if(!empty($game) && !empty($name) && !empty($date) && !empty($sessionId))
    {
        $sql="Insert into `GameDetails` (`SessionID`,`Game`,`Username`,`AvgMeditation`,`MaxMeditation',`AvgAttention` ,`MaxAttention`,`Score`,`Date`,`RawFile' ,`EEGFile', `MedFile', `AttFile') values 
        ('$sessionId','$game','$name','$avgMed','$maxMed','$avgAttn','$maxAttn','$score','$date','$rawFile','$EEGFile','$medFile','$attFile') ";

        $result=mysql_query($sql);

        if($result)
        {
            $count= mysql_affected_rows();
            if($count > 0)
            {
                $flag="true"; //result true 

            }               

        }

        mysql_close($con);  

        echo json_encode(array("result"=>$flag));
    }
}

?>
```

I also recently made a change to the MySQL database within phpMyAdmin and added four new columns but I am sure that they are referenced correctly in the script.

Comment: `$Error_checking_and_reporting = "OFF";` - Ask yourself, *"where did I go wrong, and why isn't it showing me the errors of my ways?".*

Comment: What do you mean sorry>

Comment: This => http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` - Always, always, always. That will signal any errors found in code.

Comment: OK, but where would it tell me of the errors?

Comment: ...in your web browser, believe me. Add the following to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` including the other code above for your query. See Marc's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have multiple typos:

```
  [...snip...],`Date`,`RawFile' ,`EEGFile', `MedFile', `AttFile') values 
                              ^----------^----------^----------^--- here
```

Those should be backticks (`` ` ``), not `'` single quotes.

If you had any kind of error handling in your script, you'd have been told about the syntax errors:

```
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and on top of that, you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), so it's a good thing this query isn't working, since your syntax errors are preventing any injection attack from occurring int he first place.

Never EVER assume success when dealing with external resources, e.g. a database. Always assume failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise. There's exactly ONE way for a query to succeed, and near infinite number of reasons for them to fail.

Comment: Even without seeing the person's name who's given this answer, we'd know it was you (A regular Rembrandt) ~wink~ *a particular style* if I can say - Love that `[...snip...]` thing.